# User authentication with basic roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I'd like to use a precanned library to authentic a user and then allow each user to perform a predefined set of operations if they are in a group.

Some of the requirements are that

- It doesn't use Active Directory or a database to store users
- A user is used generically, it would be more of a user that a client service uses
- Password would be used to lookup user, username passed in could be anything, only password is relevant.
- Password would have to allow GUIDs
- Nice to have would also allow for groups to be configured and each user assigned a group or groups (group = role?)

I was thinking asp.net-membership would work, except I can't seem to find a way to configure via a configuration file.

Any ideas if something like this exists?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'll refrain from having tags in my titles going forward.  Thanks for the reasoning also.

Comment: You can't not use asp.net membership with a big chunk of config, so I'm not sure what you are referring to. Are you referring to the lack of an admin tool (for CRUD for roles, etc) here is one option: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx